# Extracting values from text files in python

Tags: python

My text file is given below:-
are

```
BEE
GEOERETORNOR� ~

freon part

Kiran Kumari

_ 3H FAP) DOB: 01/01/2003
feat / FEMALE

4382 5165 5729

aeart-arm arat art aferare
```

From this text file, I successfully extracted DOB. My problem is how can I extract a line before DOB (which has a name). Which python function should use for this

Comment: why not split the string on new line?

Comment: In extraction code I used split function .I am asking for check and as well as logic for extracting name before dob

Comment: can you share the code and output?

Comment: You should format the text file as code (use Ctrl-K to indent it by 4 spaces) so that lines are not joined.

Comment: first get all lines as list, next check every line until you find line which has `DOB` and get its index and next get `all_lines[index-2]` to get line with name.

Comment: I am very grateful if you share the code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split method to get the line before the text "DOB" like this.

```
f = open('filename')

for line in f:
    if ('DOB' in line):
        req = line.split('DOB')[0]
        print(req)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
#Open the text file and read the lines
with open("try.txt") as f:
    x = (f.readlines())

#Create two list for index with name and for dob
needed_idx = []
dob= []

for idx,val in enumerate(x):
    if "DOB" in val:
        v = val.index(":")
        d = val[v+ 2:v + 12]
        dob.append(d)
        needed_idx.append(idx-2)

#Create a dict to map the name and DOB
map_idx = {}

for i in range(len(needed_idx)):
    map_idx[x[needed_idx[i]]] = dob[i]
```

Comment: It is not working for me.

Comment: oh!, whats the error, can you please share the code and the error?

Comment: It gives me blank output

Comment: ok, can you please try printing the lists(x,needed_idx,dob) and share the output here, so that I can check it. Without the actual code you tried, I can't guess where it went wrong. I assumed the text file is similar format what you have pasted and wrote the code. Dont worry about people negative voting, its a process for learning.